# Apples ZoomingPDFViewer Example - Object creation

Tags: objective-c, ios

I'm currently working on an App which should display and allow users to zoom a PDF page.
Therefore I was looking on the Apple example ZoomingPDFViewer.
Basically I understand the sample code.
But a few lines are not obvious to me.

Link to the sample code:
http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#samplecode/ZoomingPDFViewer/Introduction/Intro.html

in PDFView.m:

```
//Set the layer's class to be CATiledLayer.
+ (Class)layerClass {
    return [CATiledLayer class];
}
```

What does the code above do?

And the second code snippet I don't understand in PDFView.m again:

```
self = [super initWithFrame:frame];
    if (self) {        
        CATiledLayer *tiledLayer = (CATiledLayer *)[self layer];
        ...
```

I know it creates a CATiledLayer object. But how it will be created is not clear to me.

I hope someone could give me a short answer to my question because I don't want to use code which I don't understand.

Thank you!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The TiledPDFView.h class is a subclass of UIView, so you can see what documentation UIView has on that method. According to the [docs I see](http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#documentation/uikit/reference/uiview_class/uiview/uiview.html), it looks like:

> layerClass - Implement this method only if you want your view to use a different Core Animation layer for its backing store. For example, if you are using OpenGL ES to do your drawing, you would want to override this method and return the CAEAGLLayer class.

So it seems that it is asking the Core Animation system to use a tiled-layer. Further docs from `CATiledLayer`:

> CATiledLayer is a subclass of CALayer providing a way to
>   asynchronously provide tiles of the layer's content, potentially
>   cached at multiple levels of detail.
>        As more data is required by the renderer, the layer's drawLayer:inContext: method is called on one or more background
>   threads to supply the drawing operations to fill in one tile of data.
>   The clip bounds and CTM of the drawing context can be used to
>   determine the bounds and resolution of the tile being requested.
>        Regions of the layer may be invalidated using the setNeedsDisplayInRect: method however the update will be asynchronous.
>   While the next display update will most likely not contain the updated
>   content, a future update will.

Comment: Thank you Scott. Your answer kicks me in the right direction.